# Adding an key to a existing (or not) array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I got this code:

```
if( empty ($cache[$id]) ) {
    $arr[$id] = @TIMENOW;
    setcookie('id', cArr($arr, 'set'), -1, @PATH);
} else {
    $cache[$id] = @TIMENOW;
    setcookie('id', cArr($cache, 'set'), -1, @PATH);
}
```

And it is adding only one key, to the `cookie`, if I'll go to the another thread , it'll reset the array, and won't add more keys. I mean, if the user goes to the thread with `id` 1 then `if( empty ($cache[1]) )` is adding 1, instead it'll update existing value, AND if user will go now to the thread with ID 5, it will do the same, and `if( empty ($cache[5]) )` is empty , then it'll add the key with ID 5 to the array so I'll have both keys now: 1 and 5.

Hope you got it. If you don't , feel free to ask for whatever you wan't, I'll reply for all of your quesitons.

Comment: What's with the error-suppressing `@` in `@TIMENOW` and `@PATH`? Are you implying that `"TIMENOW"` and `"PATH"` are valid values if those respective constants are not defined?

Comment: Show the `cArr()` function which is part of your problem.

Comment: @mario This is not the part of my problem, please read the question one more time, I just wan't to add another array key, cArr is just for serializing the array...

Comment: @BoltClock
What are you talking about? Cookie is added - so `PATH` is DEFINED, even if TIMENOW will be undefined (but it is defined) it will add an empty array with key of `$id`.

Comment: @Lucas: If the constants are guaranteed to be defined the `@`s aren't necessary, and if a constant isn't defined the default value used is its string name, not `NULL`. And in case you're thinking of using `@` simply as a sigil for a constant (like `$` for variables)... don't.

Comment: If `TIMENOW` and `PATH` are meant to be constants, putting the `@` before them won't make them report as a blank value if they're not defined: http://codepad.org/9x9MBsAF

Comment: Thanks, anyway, both of them are surely defined.

Comment: You could use `defined()` though: http://codepad.org/pT0plos1

Comment: Oh-my , no one can help , but everyone is voting down my question without even leaving a comment. What a poor community.

Comment: @JaredFarrish
You don't help me. I said, both are defined so with `@` or without, it is supposed to be working because they're defined.

Comment: No offense intended, I'm just trying to show you something that is not doing what is intended (whether it's defined or not). And no, I don't understand what the actual question is asking.

Comment: Comments were left, but not answered. Question is incomplete, which is what downvotes are for. If you can't be bothered to explain your problem in detail, or provide relevant code, then suit yourself. The @ and constant discussion is very much not relevant, btw.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your tip. Which part exactly you don't understand? I'll try to explain as much as I can.

Comment: @mario 
I explained everything I want to reach. You don't understand something? I don't understand, why you won't just logout from SO when you're not able to activate your brain :)

Comment: So you're saying the update branch of you logic never runs, and instead you always have a cookie with just one saved ID? (And let's keep the personal attacks out of the comments.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what you're doing in `cArr()`. But without it, this will add to your cookie for each new thread a user visits.

```
//get previous values
$id = $_GET['thread_id'];
$cache = array_key_exists('id', $_COOKIE) ? unserialize($_COOKIE['id']) : array();

//add to $cache
$cache[$id] = TIMENOW;
setcookie('id', serialize(cArr($cache, 'set')), -1, PATH);
```

**WARNING:** But keep in mind, that with just setting a cookie, your webserver can be exploited. So better not use `searialize` and `unserialize` to store simple static values inside your cookie.

Comment: I think whatever `cArr()` is doing includes serialization.

Comment: cArr, is serializing the array - without 'set' parameter , it'll unserialize instead. But let's talk about your answer: there is a cookie named `$_COOKIE['threads_last']` and when it contains an array: `array(123 => 138745690);` where `123` is the thread id, and value is the unix time stamp. Now, if I wan't to enter another thread, this array is overwritting , instead of adding another key to the array. Hope you understand my question now :). And REALLY thank you for your answer! I've voted up!

Comment: You're probably right, but because I can't see it, I wanted to make sure the reader knows it needs to be serialized.

Comment: @Lucas - That would be because it appears you're creating a new array with the first branch (when the value is `empty()`). You really need to ADD it to the `$cache` array built from the cookie, not create a new `$arr` as in your example. This is what this answer demonstrates.

Comment: Please look here: http://pastebin.com/91Y7MXW2 where I've explained much, please read the comments also.

Comment: @Lucas - This part doesn't look right (from the first branch): `convert_bbarray_cookie(serialize($arr), `. Shouldn't it be `$cache`?

Comment: In you're link, you're still serializing the empty $arr variable. Also, there's no need to test if $cache[$id] is empty, because you're running the same code if it's empty or if it's not.

Comment: @Lucas - Also, I think in the end your `IF` statement is really unnecessary (see munch's answer); you're setting the time for the ID regardless. So you're doing the same thing twice.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Omg, I've totally forgot about this , and I didn't changed the serialize($arr) to the serialize ($cache) , now it's working very well. You can create an answer with that so I can accept it :p.